# jQuery and prototype don't work together with Array.prototype.reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, javascript-framework, conflict

I use prototype.js and jquery together and I get this error message

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_reverse' (Chrome)`

I called `jQuery.noConflict` before

I'm using `jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;` to have reverse function on jQuery collection

Comment: Why would you use prototype if you already have jQuery?

Comment: I use typo3 on this site and an extension relies on prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prototype overwrites the native `Array.protoype.reverse` Function and saves the original in `Array.prototype._reverse`.

This snippet takes account of that

```
if (typeof []._reverse == 'undefined') {
    $.fn.reverse = Array.prototype.reverse;
} else {
    $.fn.reverse = Array.prototype._reverse;
}
```

---

### old wrong solution

```js
// for compatibility with prototype.js
if (![]._reverse) {
  []._reverse = [].reverse;
}
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery in noconflict mode you'll have to add the reverse function to

```
jQuery.fn.reverse
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I wanted to answer the question for myself :) Just checking if I'm correct

Comment: You are right, but this is not the problem. `$.fn` is called inside function block with local `$` var. I'll change my question though